Getting undeclared identifier error because _exists(tokenId) function doesn't exist (was removed from?) in ERC721
I am trying to create a smart contract for minting soulbound tokens. I found that there's a ERC5192 standard for soulbound tokens (although, for some reason, there's no implementation from openzeppelin).
I'm using the implementation proposed by TimDaub here: https://github.com/attestate/ERC5192/blob/main/src/ERC5192.sol
The problem is that when I inherit from this contract, I get the "undeclared identifier error" because of _exists(tokenId) function. Apparently, openzeppelin's ERC721.sol once had this _exists(tokenId) function but now it got removed?
So, the question is: what should I do with it?
First solution would be to write _exists(tokenId) function by myself inside ERC5192.sol. But then I have supportsInterface and would it still return that the identifier for my contract is IERC5192?
Second solution would be to just give up on using ERC5192 from TimDaub's github and just write my own implementation.
What should I do? BTW, I'm new to solidity so the answer may be obvious but I'm stuck^^

you should use openzeppelin v4.9.*. openzeppelin v5 is not compatible with v4.

@EthanOK Thanks, this worked for VScode :) Do you know if I can upgrade to openzeppelin v5 in Remix as well? Is it even possible?

guy.
Me too. But in my understanding, _exists is old function?
  //to add _exists.
  mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;

  function _exists(uint256 tokenId) internal view returns (bool) {
      return _owners[tokenId] != address(0);
  }

to add "_exists" is simple, like above.
but use "_ownerOf" is newer way.

       require(_ownerOf(tokenId) != address(0), "Token does not exist");

